# Showing virus scan results from an API and a CSV file

Tags: python, json, csv

I am utilizing an API module for interacting with virustotal.com in order to get AntiVirus results based of SHA256 hashes. The code I have is working but I feel like it can be improved greatly. I think that I am brute forcing my way to some of the text fields I am looking for. Any suggestions on optimization would be greatly appreciated.

Python Code:

```
import csv
import time

def virustotal(hashvalue):
    from virus_total_apis import PublicApi as VirusTotalPublicApi

    API_KEY = 'deadbeef12345facefaceface555555555555555555555555555555555555555'
    vt = VirusTotalPublicApi(API_KEY)
    response = vt.get_file_report(hashvalue)
    return response

with open('C://SHA256.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        tempString = str(row)
        tempIndex = tempString.index(',')
        filename = tempString[2:tempIndex-1]
        filehash = tempString[tempIndex+3:-2]
        results = str(virustotal(filehash))
        try:
            tempposit1 = results.index('positives')
            tempposit2 = results.index(',', tempposit1)
            positive = results[tempposit1 + 11:tempposit2]
            temptotal = results.index("'total':")
            temptotal2 = results.index(',', temptotal)
            total = results[temptotal+8:temptotal2]
            finalresults = positive.strip() + "/" + total.strip()
        except ValueError:
            finalresults = "Not_Found"
        print(filename + "," + filehash + "," + finalresults)
        time.sleep(15) #needed delay due to API restrictions
```

SHA256.csv - example (input data that is being read)

```
hplgtv_enxml.dll,DDBC281FFE95DDCBE1CC67DF475BC4D553C27306CF978108DE4B6E6ECCF87B69
nsi.dll,732F77DC897A423AFC2A7502D2E103829A3960656A103A2243B52A7F00A40556
hplgtv_timages.dll,DF00AB06ACE714D31C9B592798C3359174198C0D0FB022889F2736F28F7E17C2
```

Results for `hplgtv_enxml.dll` from `Virustotal.com`:

```
{
  "response_code": 200,
  "results": {
    "scan_id": "ddbc281ffe95ddcbe1cc67df475bc4d553c27306cf978108de4b6e6eccf87b69-1284841383",
    "verbose_msg": "Scan finished, information embedded",
    "sha1": "4b57042dd08dbca1de775f56dc8ff3939e6dc1e2",
    "total": 43,
    "positives": 0,
    "sha256": "ddbc281ffe95ddcbe1cc67df475bc4d553c27306cf978108de4b6e6eccf87b69",
    "scan_date": "2010-09-18 20:23:03",
    "resource": "DDBC281FFE95DDCBE1CC67DF475BC4D553C27306CF978108DE4B6E6ECCF87B69",
    "permalink": "https://www.virustotal.com/file/ddbc281ffe95ddcbe1cc67df475bc4d553c27306cf978108de4b6e6eccf87b69/analysis/1284841383/",
    "scans": {
      "AhnLab-V3": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "2010.09.19.00"
      },
      "eTrust-Vet": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100917",
        "version": "36.1.7862"
      },
      "nProtect": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "2010-09-18.01"
      },
      "AntiVir": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "8.2.4.58"
      },
      "Norman": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "6.06.06"
      },
      "TrendMicro-HouseCall": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "9.120.0.1004"
      },
      "Sophos": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "4.57.0"
      },
      "McAfee-GW-Edition": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "2010.1C"
      },
      "PCTools": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "7.0.3.5"
      },
      "F-Secure": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "9.0.15370.0"
      },
      "GData": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "21"
      },
      "Authentium": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "5.2.0.5"
      },
      "CAT-QuickHeal": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "11.00"
      },
      "Prevx": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "3.0"
      },
      "Microsoft": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "1.6201"
      },
      "Jiangmin": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "13.0.900"
      },
      "McAfee": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "5.400.0.1158"
      },
      "ClamAV": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "0.96.2.0-git"
      },
      "DrWeb": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "5.0.2.03300"
      },
      "ViRobot": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "2010.9.18.4048"
      },
      "Rising": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "22.65.05.00"
      },
      "Sunbelt": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "6894"
      },
      "TheHacker": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "6.7.0.0.023"
      },
      "AVG": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "9.0.0.851"
      },
      "VirusBuster": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "12.65.13.0"
      },
      "Antiy-AVL": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "2.0.3.7"
      },
      "K7AntiVirus": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "9.63.2552"
      },
      "Comodo": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "6121"
      },
      "Fortinet": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "4.1.143.0"
      },
      "BitDefender": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "7.2"
      },
      "Symantec": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "20101.1.1.7"
      },
      "Avast": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "4.8.1351.0"
      },
      "SUPERAntiSpyware": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "4.40.0.1006"
      },
      "Avast5": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "5.0.594.0"
      },
      "eSafe": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100917",
        "version": "7.0.17.0"
      },
      "F-Prot": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "4.6.1.107"
      },
      "Emsisoft": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "5.0.0.37"
      },
      "Ikarus": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "T3.1.1.88.0"
      },
      "Panda": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "10.0.2.7"
      },
      "TrendMicro": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "9.120.0.1004"
      },
      "Kaspersky": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "7.0.0.125"
      },
      "NOD32": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100918",
        "version": "5460"
      },
      "VBA32": {
        "result": "None",
        "detected": false,
        "update": "20100917",
        "version": "3.12.14.0"
      }
    },
    "md5": "c5de5387228d0d71152d62a9fd1b7a66",
    "response_code": 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

> I think that I am brute forcing my way to some of the text fields I am looking for.

Indeed.

```
csv.reader()
```

Each row returned by `csv.reader(0)` is a list of strings. So your line

```py
tempString = str(row)
```

is undoing the work `csv` did for you (which is the entire reason for using `csv`). Instead, you should do this:

```py
readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
for row in readCSV:
    filename = row[0]
    filehash = row[1]
```

### Use the `dict` returned by `vt.get_file_report()`

<sup>***Edit:*** my original response directed the OP to use `json` library to parse JSON-formatted text. That was incorrect, as the returned data was already parsed by `json` library.</sup>

The `response` returned from your `virustotal()` function is a `dict` of the key-value data shown in your "Results for `hplgtv_enxml.dll` from `Virustotal.com`" section.

Thus, you just need to access the appropriate key of the `dict` (specifically, the keys in the `results` `dict` of the returned data). To access the `"positives"` and `"total"` fields you were looking for, they are under the `"results"` key:

```py
results = virustotal(filehash)
positive = results['results']['positives']
total = results['results']['total']
```

Because everything you want is under the `"results"` subdictionary, I would just reference it (`['results']`) at the end of the `virustotal()` call).

Here are the combined suggested modifications (using the list that `csv.reader()` returns, and using `json.loads()`):

```py
for row in readCSV:
        filename = row[0]
        filehash = row[1]
        try:
            results = virustotal(filehash)['results']
            positive = results['positives']
            total = results['total']
            finalresults = "{}/{}".format(positive, total)
        except ValueError:
            finalresults = "Not_Found"
        print "{},{},{}".format(filename, filehash, finalresults)
```

Comment: Hi scottbb, I am utilizing your suggestions, but getting json error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/vtscript.py", line 19, in <module>
    results = json.loads(virustotal(filehash))['results']
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 312, in loads
    s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'dict'

Comment: My apologies. I didn't use the `virus_total_apis` library that you included. I made the invalid assumption that `vt.get_file_report()` returned JSON-formatted text. It returns the parsed `dict` of the JSON. So you don't even need the `json` library. Instead, just use `results = virustotal(filehash)['results']`.

Comment: You could utilize `format` syntax further:
`finalresults = "{positives}/{total}".format(**virustotal(filehash)['results'])`

Answer (score 4):

Simplifying @scottbb's answer even further:

You could use tuple unpacking to read the `filename` and `filehash` and make use of `format`s syntax to use a dictionary for its values:

```
for row in readCSV:
    filename, filehash = row
    try:
        results = virustotal(filehash)['results']
        finalresults = "{positives}/{total}".format(**results)
    except ValueError:
        finalresults = "Not_Found"
    print "{},{},{}".format(filename, filehash, finalresults)
```

Or:

```
for row in readCSV:
    try:
        results = virustotal(row[1])['results']
        finalresults = "{positives}/{total}".format(**results)
    except ValueError:
        finalresults = "Not_Found"
    print "{},{},{result}".format(*row, result=finalresults)
```

Or:

```
    print "{1},{2},{0}".format(finalresults, *row)
```

Or (Python 3.6+):

```
    print(f"{row[0]},{row[1]},{finalresults}")
```

Comment: I had never really considered using tuple unpacking with `format()`, but it makes perfect sense. Nice!